# Should we communicate the shipping *progress* here, or will it be redundant?

Tags: email, options, customer-experience, many-options, shipping

We're a small e-commerce business. A few weeks after we've shipped an order, we'll be checking in with customers to see if everything's okay. The e-mail will have three clickable options for them to choose from:

- I received the order and I'm happy with it.
- I received the order, but I'm *not* happy with it.
- I haven't received the order yet.

My colleague came up with these icons to illustrate the above options:

[image]

<sup>(Please ignore the smiley shadow that's on the wrong side, and the Mastercard-only implication)</sup>

My overall feeling is that this is slightly more on the cryptic side, and people would be lazy (and rightfully so) to figure it out. I believe this communication needs to be more "*in-your-face*", straight to the point, and therefore stripped down.

- I'm thinking that the first two icons in each row (the card and the truck) could be redundant, and may have to be removed (including the arrows). I'd only keep the box with a checkmark and a smiley.
- For the third option (*haven't received*), I'd use the a truck instead of the box, and a neutral smiley. (Can't use a box with a question mark, because that could lead the customers to think they may not receive it at all.)

However, the colleague believes there needs to be the indication of a progress, so having all 4 is justified.

My question is, would the last two icons alone, with the help of the contrast in meaning between them, be enough to make it intuitive? Or do we really need to start with the payment icon?

Answer (score 3):

#### Plain language requires less interpretation than icons. Just ask them.

[Icons alone have been shown to be open to interpretation](http://To%20help%20overcome%20the%20ambiguity%20that%20almost%20all%20icons%20face,%20a%20text%20label%20must%20be%20present%20alongside%20an%20icon%20to%20clarify%20its%20meaning%20in%20that%20particular%20context.%20(And%20even%20if%20you%E2%80%99re%20using%20a%20standard%20icon,%20it%E2%80%99s%20often%20safer%20to%20include%20a%20label,%20especially%20if%20you%20slightly%20altered%20the%20icon%20to%20match%20your%20aesthetic%20preferences%20or%20constraints.)). Your current approach has 12 icons (plus 9 arrows) spread across 3 rows. **Why not just ask the question?**

**Option 1: clickable statements**

Replace the icon sequences with 3 statements (like you've stated above).

People don't want to use their time to interpret icons, especially if they're already not satisfied with your project.

**Option 2: take them to a feedback form**

This gives an opportunity for leaving more detailed feedback about their order. Since *satisfaction level* is predicated on having received the order, leave it out to start with:

[image]

Right now, you're trying to interpret what you already wrote which is fairly clear.
Any icon-only solution forces a user:

- To read each icon in a sequence
- To remember in the sequence, the condition of the previous icon
- To correctly interpret the meaning based on the sum of icons
- Compare them to the other two sequences, to make sure they've chosen the correct option

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mix of concepts and that's what confronts both opinions, yours and your colleague's.

What matters most to the end consumer?

1. The whole purchase progress has been satisfactory?
2. The receipt of the purchase has been satisfactory

If I put myself in the role of the final consumer, what interests me the most is the final receipt of the purchase, unless there has been a problem. Only in this last case I'm interested in knowing the progress to see if it's possible to detect where the failure was.

Following the three statements you describe at the beginning of the question...

> - I received the order and I'm happy with it.
> - I received the order, but I'm not happy with it.
> - I haven't received the order yet.

...showing the progress is not that important, you are just talking about "receiving the order", not about the agreement with the delivery process. If this is the case, the entire process of images with arrows is a totally unnecessary information.

The three states are:

1. Received → Happy
2. Received → Unhappy
3. Not Received → Unhappy

You only have to design four icons and three combinations (Not received and happy doesn't exist):

`Received` – `Not Received` – `Happy` – `Unhappy`

[image]

The last case could be a button that accesses the complete purchase process steps.

<sub>*Icon from [thenounproject.com](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=delivery%20hand&i=2351905)*</sub>